# Is the use of 'had' in this context correct?

Tags: grammar

"Whenever I felt doubtful whether she had left I'd look through a small hole in the gate and find out she was there. Always, ever since. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct in this sentence.
We use the Past Perfect Tense here (had left), because it is important to show that the event (her leaving) happened before the other events in this situation.